# Decision making in SSRS - SQL with parameters and filters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Suppose the following SQL table :

[image]

- I want to create a report using a stored procedure that takes column `Type` as a filter. Based on that parameter i want to select the respective field and display it in the report. Note that the `type1` and `type2` fields can come from a different table and/or may be more than one field per `Type` .

What is the best practice for decision - making in SQL and SSRS filtering patterns ?

I found out that I can do something like this :

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[blahblah] @Type int
as
IF @Type = 1
    select type1
    from sampleTable
ELSE
    select type2
    from sampleTable
 GO
```

but i don't know if this is the indicating way of doing things . Any help appreciated .

Comment: You actually have found the easiest (preferred) way of doing this.  Good job!

Comment: Yes but how do i create a tabular report that shows different fields of the dataset depending on Type in SSRS @tgolisch

Comment: Use an alias so that the field name returned to SSRS is always the same. e.g. `SELECT type1 as TypeColumn FROM sampletable` .